# Xcode UITest and Bluetooth: Searching for Peripherals returns no peripherals

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, xctest, uitest

I have an app which I want to test using `XCTest` in Xcode. For testing, I need to scan for devices inside my Testcase to execute a specific behavior.

The problem is, that I can not find any peripherals when scanning for them, although I have code which is working fine inside the original app. Could it be that `XCtest` does not allow bluetooth communication triggered from the `UITests`?

I'm at a point, where I have no further ideas how to go on. Maybe someone has a good hint for me.

My code looks as followed: The `UITests` are written in Swift, and I have a Helper Class to execute Bluetooth specific code in Objective-C.
So first I create this Objective-C helper class in my Swift file as a global variable:

```
var helper : ObjectiveCTestsHelper?
```

In the setup function of the UITest File, I initialize this variable:

```
helper = ObjectiveCTestsHelper()
```

In the test function, I then execute the bluetooth specific function and wait for it with a dummy expectation, so that the `UITest` does not terminate:

```
let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Dummy")
helper!.scanForDevices()
self.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1000)
```

The scanForDevices function looks like this:

```
- (void) scanForDevices {
    self.bleScanningModel = [[BluetoothScanningModel alloc] init];

    [self.bleScanningModel startScan:50.0
                             repeats:YES
                          completion:^(NSDictionary *periperals) {
                              //here no peripherals
                          }];
}
```

The startScan method scans for devices:

```
- (void)startScan:(NSTimeInterval)period
          repeats:(BOOL)repeats
       completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *periperals))completion {

    if (self.isScanning) {
        int a = 3;
        return;
    }
    self.isScanning = true;

    foundPeriperals = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    self.completionHandler = completion;
    self.repeats = repeats;

    scanPeriodTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: period
                                                       target: self
                                                     selector: @selector(periodTimerFired:)
                                                     userInfo: nil
                                                      repeats: self.repeats];

    [self checkIfBluetoothIsPoweredUp:^(BOOL success) {
            [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices: nil 
                                                   options: nil];
    }];
}
```

Basically, it just checks if `Bluetooth` is powered on, and then scans for peripherals. After 5 Seconds, a timer is fired to get back to the startScan method to execute a function based on the found peripherals.
And here is my problem. I execute **scanForPeripheralsWithServices** but the function **didDiscoverPeripheral**, is not called by the central manager when a peripheral is found, so I have no peripherals to work with.

Could it be that `Bluetooth` is not allowed to be executed from `UITests` directly?

I hope someone can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Where do you run your tests? Simulator or device?

Comment: I run the tests on a physical device, an iPhone 5S

Comment: Isn't it that the app needs to have a permission to use the Bluetooth? And when you want to use Bluetooth within you UITest it's another app (the test runner), not your actual test. I'm not sure how to turn on this privilege for the runner app as it doesn't have any UI. Maybe check in settings? I have no idea if the runner app will be present in settings.

Comment: Anyway. Why do you need to access Bluetooth in the UI Test?

Comment: I already checked the settings and added bluetooth-central and bluetooth-peripheral in the plist file of my UITest Target. Anyway, I haven't found other bluetooth specific settings. The thing is that when I check the state of the centralManager, I can see that it is in State CBManagerStatePoweredOn, which means that I can somehow interact with the central Manager.

Comment: I need this, as I have a bluetooth device, which is in a state which waits for the user to press a button. The action behind the button press can also be triggered by a bluetooth command, which I want to send with my UITest, so I can continue with the UITests without having a user pressing the button. To simplify my problem, I just scan now for devices to see if bluetooth is working.

Comment: @Phil_G Hi Phil. Can you provide your test code example of how you implemented CoreBluetooth with tests, because I configured my UITest Target .plist file, but I'm not getting CBCentralManager in the poweredOn state? Need this asap if you have it... And in the end, did you manage this to work fully? Thank you!

Comment: @BlueDev Hi, sorry, I can not help you further on that as I do not have the code anymore. Best regards